# how to convert a string to timetuple in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a Dataframe as:

```
df = {'date':['20170101', '20170102', '20170103', '20170104']}
```

I want to convert `'20170101'` to `'2017-01-01 00:00:00'`

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Flow this link and you will get answer [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834732/convert-pandas-datetime-column-yyyy-mm-dd-to-yyymmdd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `pandas.DataFrame` you can do that with:

#### Code:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

#### Test Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['20170101', '20170102', '20170103', '20170104']})
df['date2'] = df['date'].apply(lambda d: dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y%m%d'))
df['date3'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
print(df)
```

#### Results:

```
       date      date2      date3
0  20170101 2017-01-01 2017-01-01
1  20170102 2017-01-02 2017-01-02
2  20170103 2017-01-03 2017-01-03
3  20170104 2017-01-04 2017-01-04
```

Answer (score 4):

You could convert your date time string to `datetime` object. And then get whatever format you want:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime("20170103", "%Y%m%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Output:

```
"2017-01-03 00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how the string is built (i.e. `YYYYMMDD`) you can simply use this:

```
def f(s):
    return '{}-{}-{} 00:00:00'.format(s[:4],s[4:6],s[6:])
s = '20170101'

f(s)
Out[7]: '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
```